# Can't get sum of numbers from txt file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Project:

I am working on a node.js training module and one of the small projects wants me to do the following:

> Instructions: Build a Node application called account.js which takes
>   user inputs via the command line to register transactions. The user
>   must be able to input:
>
> - total - this should tally up all of the money in the bank balance and    display it for the user.
> - deposit  - this should add a positive amount to the bank    balance. Do not display the balance to the user.
> - withdraw  - this should add a negative amount to the bank    balance. Do not display the balance to the user.
> - lotto - 90% of the time, this should subtract a small account from    the user's balance. The other 10% of the time, this should add a
>     large amount to the user's balance.
>
> Every transaction should be logged in a .txt file.
>
> Hints: Consider making a series of if-then or switch-case statements
>   to identify the type of transaction and the amount involved.

Problem:

I cannot get the sum of all entries in the txt document. I got it to deposit using the following code:

```
function deposit() {
   // We will add the value to the bank file.
   fs.appendFileSync("bank.txt", amount);

}
```

This code will allow me to write entries to the bank.txt file using the following line in my terminal:

```
node banking.js deposit 300
```

After inserting the numbers 300, 500, 222 and when I open the txt file the numbers look like `300500222`

Now when I want to see the sum I created the total function which looks like this:

```
function total() {

   sum = 0;

   for(let i=0; i < bankAccount.length; i++){
       sum+=bankAccount[i];
   }
   console.log(sum);

}
```

I will run the following line in my terminal:

```
node banking.js total
```

And my output will be:

```
0300500222
```

If you notice it adds everything together like one string and adds a 0 to the front.

What I have done:

I have tried various methods I could not find much about this on stack or online. I tried to take the actual text file contents and use split() and then join to see if I could convert it to an array and I was not successful it just separated every single individual number and not the numbers as a whole. I also tried to use JSON.stringify then parse and then try to convert but I had a hard time and it did not work.

What I am asking for:

Just need some guidance as to how I would get this done once I get the initial deposit and total correct I can work on the other parts of the project on my own.

Here is the full code of what I have so far:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var bankAccount = fs.readFileSync("bank.txt","UTF-8");
let inputString = process.argv;
let action = inputString[2];
let amount = inputString[3];

if(action == "deposit"){
  deposit();
}else if(action == "withdraw"){
   withdraw();
}else if(action == "total"){
   total();
}else if(action == "lotto"){
   lotto();
}else{
   console.log("Please input whether it is a deposit, withdraw, total, or you wanna try the lotto?");
}

function total() {

   sum = 0;   
   for(let i=0; i < bankAccount.length; i++){
       sum+=bankAccount[i];
   }
   console.log(sum); 
}

function deposit() {

   fs.appendFileSync("bank.txt", amount);

}
```

Comment: When you read files, you get a `string`. The `+` operator with a `string` corresponds to a concatenation, not sum. So you need to cast the `string` you get from file into a `int` : `var bankAccount = parseInt(fs.readFileSync("bank.txt","UTF-8"));`

Comment: Well, the first thing you need to do is add some kind of delimiter to the text file so you know where the first deposit ends and the second begins. Then you can `split` on that.

Comment: A better option would be to use JSON to store transactions and simply `require` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a delimiter to be able to keep transactions separated. Here is an example using `space` as a delimiter with your original code:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var bankAccount = fs.readFileSync("bank.txt","UTF-8");
let inputString = process.argv;
let action = inputString[2];
let amount = inputString[3];
const DELIMITER = ' ';

if(action == "deposit"){
  deposit();
}else if(action == "withdraw"){
  withdraw();
}else if(action == "total"){
  total();
}else if(action == "lotto"){
  lotto();
}else{
  console.log("Please input whether it is a deposit, withdraw, total, or you wanna try the lotto?");
}

function total() {

  const transactions = bankAccount.split(DELIMITER)

  sum = 0;
  for(let i=0; i < transactions.length; i++){
    sum+= Number(transactions[i]);
  }
  console.log(sum);
}

function deposit() {

  fs.appendFileSync("bank.txt", DELIMITER + amount);

}
```

Comment: Life saver makes a ton of sense I could not get this at all I tried for hours thank you!